# Laravel: unique URL & profile for each record

Tags: php, laravel

Currently I have a table with a list of 'lawyers', for example. I am able to show a list of lawyers by state like so in routes/web:

```
// Lawyers per state

Route::get('/lawyers/{state}', function ($state) {
$states = DB::table('states')->get();
$lawyers = DB::table('lawyers')->join('states', 'states.abbr', '=', 'lawyers.state')
                                       ->where('states.abbr', '=', $state)
                                       ->orderBy('lawyers.featured', 'desc')
                                       ->get(['lawyers.*', 'states.name AS state_name']);
$statename = DB::table('states')->where('abbr', $state)->value('name');
return view('pages.lawyers', ['lawyers' => $lawyers, 'states' => $states, 'statename' => $statename]);
});
```

This correctly shows a list of lawyers.

What I want is to create a unique URL for each lawyer, like a profile page view with the url structure `/lawyers/{state}/{firstname}-{lastname}-{zipcode}` so clicking on their name in the list goes to the lawyers profile.

What is the correct way to accomplish this so that:

1. The lawyer url shows the `lawyers.profile` view
2. The lawyer name from the list links to the correct URL

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just add more route parameters, like you did for `{state}`:

```
Route::get('/lawyers/{state}/{firstname}-{lastname}-{zipcode}', function ($state, $firstname, $lastname, $zipcode) {
    // Logic
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In web.php you can do it. Also used cache for during $minutes for one time db query executed

```
$minutes = 10;
$lawyers = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Cache::remember('', $minutes, function () {
    return DB::table('lawyer')->get([
        'firstname',
        'lastname',
        'zipcode',
        'state',
    ]);
});

foreach ($lawyers as $lawyer) {
    $url  = sprintf('/%s/%s-%s-%s', $lawyer->state, $lawyer->firstname, $lawyer->lastname, $lawyer->zipcode);
    Route::get($url, 'your action');
}
```

Comment: Where would the view be added to this to show a profile view for each lawyer like `lawyers.profile`?

Comment: **Route::get($url, function () {// your code; return view('your-view');});**

Comment: or using Controllere **Route::get($url, 'YourController@yorMethod');** see [https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/routing#named-routes)